# WPF clear datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In MainWindow.xaml.cs I have button to set DataContext:

```
private void RedView_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new RedViewModel();
    }
```

In MainWindow.xaml I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="redViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:RedViewModel}">
        <views:RedView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="5" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

After clicking on the button, DataContext is set properly

How to return to a previous state ? (I mean clear MainWindow, just buttons)

My goal is to create buttons dynamically in MainWindow.xaml with access to different Views and change those views everytime is need by returning to MainView and generate buttons again.

I was trying to search but I didn't know how to ask the right question.
Thanks.

Comment: You would use another data template and assign another viewmodel. Instead of manipulating `DataContext` directly the right way is to modify just property of main view model. While technically you can clear view with `DataContext = null`, I'd use *empty* view for when there is nothing.

Comment: What is the "previous state", `DataContext = null` probably? As a note `DataContext="{Binding}"` is usually redundant (unless your RedView class is implemented incorrectly and explicitly sets its own DataContext during initialization).

Comment: If you are using MVVM, it's not UI layer who should decide about the `DataContext`. Your VM layer should change the property to which `DataContext` is bound. That way there is no problem to restore the property value.

Comment: But how to access and set MainWindow 'DataContext = null' from another View ?

Comment: Maybe someone would share a little bit of code how to do this properly ?